# Is there an application that can tell you what DLL's and other dependencies a program uses?

Tags: windows, dll

Is there an application that can tell you what `.dll`'s and other dependencies a program uses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) can do this.

Or on a running application, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can list the DLLs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: You can also use Dependency Walker to track which DLLs are loaded at runtime dynamically using the *Profile* menu when and exe is loaded.