# How can I find out what dlls are being referenced from another dll

Tags: windows-7, windows, dll

Is it possible to find out what other dlls a certain dll is referencing? I can't run it, I just want to find out what other files it's referencing. Maybe there's a nice program out there that can find this information?

Comment: did you check this? http://superuser.com/questions/110954/is-there-an-application-that-can-tell-you-what-dlls-and-other-dependencies-a-pr

Comment: Thanks, great :) Write it as an answer and I'll mark it so you'll get the points...

Comment: the answer is in another question so you should vote there...

Comment: ok, I'll do that